# How to get the address of a global variable in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Let `x` be the address of a global variable `g` in a program at run-time. LLVM IR produces a store instruction as shown below:

```
store i32 30, i32* @g, align 4
```

I am writing an LLVM pass which will instrument the program such that `x` is passed to an instrumentation function `func(int addr)` at run-time. I can insert a call to `func` using `IRBuilder` successfully. What I am not being able to do is to insert instrumentation to collect `x`.

```
if (StoreInst *store_inst = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) {

                    Value* po = store_inst->getPointerOperand();
                    if(isa<GlobalVariable>(po)) {
                        errs() << "store [pointer]: " << *po << '\n';

                        Constant *instrument_func = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("func", Type::getVoidTy(Ctx), Type::getInt32Ty(Ctx), NULL);

                        IRBuilder<> builder(&I);
                        builder.SetInsertPoint(&B, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());

                        Value* args[] = {po};
                        builder.CreateCall(instrument_func, args);
                    }
                }
```

The result of running `opt` is :

```
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
i32* @a
 i32  call void bitcast (void (i64)* @func to void (i32)*)(i32* @a)
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

Comment: `@g` is `x`. The value of `g` as you'd think of it in a C or C++ program is `load @g`.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities either you are passing parameters of different type or of different size.

I am not quite sure but try this:

```
if (StoreInst *store_inst = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) {

                    Value* po = store_inst->getPointerOperand();
                    if(isa<GlobalVariable>(po)) {
                        errs() << "store [pointer]: " << *po << '\n';

                        Constant *instrument_func = F.getParent()->getOrInsertFunction("func", Type::getVoidTy(Ctx), Type::getInt32Ty(Ctx), NULL);

                        IRBuilder<> builder(&I);
                        builder.SetInsertPoint(&B, ++builder.GetInsertPoint());

                        std::vector<Value *> args;
                        args.push_back(po);
                        builder.CreateCall(instrument_func, args);
                    }
                }
```